# bash:terminal access to camera files? (mounted as "gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/DCIM/..." - can't find them!

Tags: usb, bash, mount, camera, ubuntu-11.04

I cannot `find` any of my camera image files (connected via USB), despite them being listed in Nautilus (Ubuntu 11.04), labeled `gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/DCIM/104_0308/...`
How can I `cd` to that location??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GVFS-mounted devices are in `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams: thanks. But: is that folder inaccessible with `find`? things like `sudo find / -iname *08.JPG` don't seem to work?

Comment: If `find` can't access it then it will tell you so.

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams it just doesn't give any results (I thought anything within the filesystem would be accessible with `find`?) -- Interestingly: `cd`ing into parent directory and do `sudo find .` gives 'Permission denied'?! - How could that be rectified??

Answer (score 4):

I am running Ubuntu 13.04. The images from my camera are located in /run/user/<user>/gvfs/gphoto2. Use the mount command to find the location.

Comment: You might also find something in `/media`

Comment: In 14.10 I find that /run/user contains directories with user IDs rather than names (107 for lightdm, 1000 for me). More importantly, though, the gvfs directory is empty, and mount shows no camera, but I have Caja showing the contents of the camera.